# can't run any python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

When trying to run any Python script - Python2 or Python3 and install pip, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inSp3ctor.py", line 22, in <module>
    from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
ImportError: No module named colorama
```

If I try to `sudo pip install colorama` it tells me that the requirement is already satisfied:

```
asdw@sasxa:~/Desktop/inSp3ctor$ sudo pip install colorama

Requirement already satisfied: colorama in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.3.9)
```

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. Is it possible to show a snippet of the python code that you are trying to execute?

Comment: Are you using any specific Virtual Environment?

Comment: I have a feeling its an envrionement issue. please least your environments and check what environment is used in first and second cases

Comment: check the version of pip and python that the module is installed for by `pip --version`. Then strictly specify python version for running the script like `python3.6 test.py`.

Comment: @Masoud i tried this also

Comment: @ParthS007 no sir

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is occurring due to different versions of python on your machine and you might be making use of python3 , so try performing `pip3 install your module name`
and re open the idle or ide and run the code

Comment: same problem !!

Comment: still the same bro